# Error 1452, no puedo crear clave foranea

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

deseo poder hacer una relación entre mis tablas:
tipo_medida con producto y tengo este error

Anteriormente ya tengo otra clave foranea en producto, no se si es debido a esto
[image: Mis tablas del proyecto]

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te dice este mensaje es que, entre los registros que ya tienes creados en la tabla donde le pones el foreign key, hay algunos que tienen definido un valor "tipo_medida" que no se corresponde con un "id_medida" de la tabla "tipo_medida".

Por poner un ejemplo, en la tabla "tipo_medida" tendrás definidos los ids 1, 2 y 3, pero en la tabla donde añades el foreign key tienes algún registro (o más) con "tipo_medida" 42.

Si te dejara definir el foreign key, tendrías que la BD tiene el foreign key pero que tienes registros que no cumplen la restricción del foreign key.

Primero tienes que normalizar los registros para asegurarte de que cumplan la restricción y luego definir el foreign key.